# Beta value of the thermistor

Tags: pcb, thermistor

Why is that there are two different Beta constants for a same thermistor even though Beta constant depends on the material?

For example: [Murata's NCU15XH103D60RC](https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/productdetail?partno=NCU15XH103D60RC) has three different beta constants:

- at B25/80: 3428,
- at B25/85: 3434,
- and at B25/100: 3455

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you link to the datasheet in question (and point to the specific page etc) where it specifies three different Beta constants? Can't find that.

Comment: ah! Um, what do you thing the "25/80", "25/85" and "25/100" mean? They have units in the datasheet, you know, and you don't need to think very hard when you realize what these units are measuring.

Answer (score 5):

The classic approach when dealing with RTD's is the [Steinhart-Hart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor#Steinhart%E2%80%93Hart_equation) equation

\$\frac{1}{T} = a b\cdot ln(R) + c\cdot ln^2(R)\$

This is a very accurate model of the characteristic change with respect to temperature.

This however is quite "complex" to deal with in real-time (if accurate temperature is require).

The [\$ \beta model\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor#B_or_%CE%B2_parameter_equation) is a special/reduce case of the Steinhart-Hart equation

\$ R = R_0 e^{\beta ( \frac{1}{T} - \frac{1}{T_0})} \$

such that:

\$a = \frac{1}{T_0} - \frac{1}{B}ln R_0\$

\$b = \frac{1}{B} \$

c = 0

It essentially sets the operating point around a given temperature. The further you drift away from this temperature, the less accurate the calculated temperature.

[image]

By providing the beta at different T0, it provides the designer the opportunity to tailor their accuracy around the temperature of interest. If you need an over-temperature warning at 85C then the beta at this temperature is of interest

Answer (score 4):

The beta model is just that -- a model.  You will get different answers for beta when you use different temperature points to estimate beta.

B25/80 is likely beta when calculated using data at 25 deg C and 80 deg C.

All those betas are closer than 1%.  If you need better, consider using a thermistor quantified with Steinhart-Hart coefficients.